# NSolve not solving

Tags: equation-solving

I've been working on a Newton Cooling equation problem for my diff equ class and cannot get `NSolve` to solve this equation. I've plugged it into Wolfram Alpha and my Ti-89 and have gotten the same answer, none of which were imaginary.
If someone point out where I'm going wrong that would be great.
Thanks.

```
NSolve[{270 = 399.99999999999966 E^(-0.3t)(0.058035714285714336 - 
 0.8705357142857142 E^(0.27999999999999997 t) + E^(0.3` t)) }, t]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[9]:= Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 270. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[9]:= Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with 
>  inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system 
>  and numericizing the result. >>
>
> {{t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.239434 + 3.14159 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.237798 - 2.70752 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.237798 + 2.70752 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.232727 - 2.27344 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.232727 + 2.27344 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.223659 - 1.83939 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.223659 + 1.83939 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.209345 - 1.40542 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.209345 + 1.40542 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.186929 - 0.971828 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.186929 + 0.971828 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.148275 - 0.540455 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.148275 + 0.540455 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.0648984 - 0.141421 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}, 
>  {t -> ConditionalExpression[
>      50. ((-0.0648984 + 0.141421 I) + (0. + 6.28319 I) C[1]), C[1] \[Element] Integers]}}
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Replace `=` by `==` immediately after `270`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [Equal (`==`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html?q=Equal) instead of [Set (`=`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html?q=Set) for the equation and add `Reals` as a third argument to `NSolve` to restrict all variables, parameters, and function values to be real

```
NSolve[270 == 399.99999999999966 E^(-0.3 t) (0.058035714285714336 - 
 0.8705357142857142 E^(0.27999999999999997 t) + E^(0.3 t)), t, Reals]
```

> `{{t -> -8.31446}, {t -> 49.2642}}`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note the difference between `=` (assignment) and `==` (equality).  Take a look at `NSolve` examples which all use `==`.

`NSolve` is limited in what sorts of equations it can solve, but when it can solve an equation, it will try to get all solutions.  The result it gives you is a fairly general one, and it's valid for any `C[1]` that is an integer.  If you substitute `0` for it, the last two solutions will be real.  These are likely the solutions your calculator finds.

To get only the real ones, you can use

```
In[]:= NSolve[
 270 == 399.99999999999966 E^(-0.3 t) (0.058035714285714336` - 
     0.8705357142857142 E^(0.27999999999999997 t) + E^(0.3` t)),
 t,
 Reals
 ]

During evaluation of In[]:= Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>

Out[]= {{t -> -8.3144621}, {t -> 49.264177}}
```

Also take a look at `FindRoot` which will use Newton's method (a numerical method) to find just one solution.  This is likely what your calculator is doing.

```
FindRoot[
 270 == 399.99999999999966 E^(-0.3 t) (0.058035714285714336` - 
     0.8705357142857142 E^(0.27999999999999997 t) + E^(0.3` t)), {t, 
  0}]
(* {t -> 49.264177} *)
```